# Multiple @RequestBody in feign client exception when executing service

Tags: spring-boot, spring-cloud-feign, feign, openfeign

I am giving call from User microservice to Account microservice via feign client. I am passing 3 request body in method call. I am getting exception when I am executing user service stating that multiple request body is present in feign call.

```
@PostMapping("/create)
ResponseEntity<Long> createAccount(@RequestBody List<UserInfo> userInfo, @RequestBody List<AddressInfo> addressInfo, @RequestBody List<OrderInfo> orderInfo);
```

Is there a limit on number of request body I can send via feign? I just don't want to club all three list under one object and want to send them separately.

Can any one please help me with this?

Answer (score 0):

You can't pass multiple Body in HTTP request (see [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Messages#:%7E:text=Bodies%20can%20be%20broadly%20divided,typically%20associated%20with%20HTML%20Forms.)). Does your Account microservice really have API that require more than one body?